# yum не может установить MariaDB 10.1

Tags: linux, mariadb, devops, yum

Centos 7. Для установки Galera-cluster требуется версия MariaDB не ниже 10.1. Подключаю репозиторий:

```
# MariaDB 10.1 CentOS repository list - created 2018-02-26 11:31 UTC
# http://downloads.mariadb.org/mariadb/repositories/
[mariadb]
name = MariaDB
baseurl = http://yum.mariadb.org/10.1/centos7-amd64
gpgkey=https://yum.mariadb.org/RPM-GPG-KEY-MariaDB
gpgcheck=1
$ yum repolist enabled
repo id                                repo name                               
status
mariadb                                MariaDB                                 
15
repolist: 15
sudo mysql --version                                                                                                                                                                                                                             
mysql  Ver 15.1 Distrib 5.5.56-MariaDB, for Linux (x86_64) using 
readline 5.1
```

Сервер был установлен, а клиент нет, версия сервера не соответствует той что мне нужна(10.1)
Проверяем кто врет, вырубаем все репы
И пытаемся найти mariadb-server

```
$ yum repolist enabled
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile

repolist: 0
```

Как видим все репы выключены, пробуем найти mariadb

```
yum search mariadb
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
====== N/S matched: mariadb ========
mariadb-libs.x86_64 : The shared libraries required for MariaDB/MySQL clients
mariadb-server.x86_64 : The MariaDB server and related files
mariadb.x86_64 : A community developed branch of MySQL

Name and summary matches only, use "search all" for everything.
```

Кэш я чистил а все равно вижу эти пакеты, как мне установить Mariadb 10.1 конкретно из тех репозиториев что я установил?

Comment: yum --enablerepo mariadb install mariadb ?

Comment: @GarfieldCat
No packages available

при активном mariadb.repo (yum repolist enabled видит)

Comment: Проверил на CentOS 6: yum --enablerepo mariadb install MariaDB-client

Answer (score 0):

Требуется очистить кэш и пересоздать его:

```
$ sudo rm -rf /var/cache/yum
$ sudo makecache
$ sudo yum search MariaDB
loaded plugins: fastestmirror
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile

================== N/S matched: mariadb==============
MariaDB-backup.x86_64 : MariaDB: a very fast and robust SQL database 
server
MariaDB-cassandra-engine.x86_64 : MariaDB: a very fast and robust SQL 
database server
MariaDB-client.x86_64 : MariaDB: a very fast and robust SQL database 
server
MariaDB-common.x86_64 : MariaDB: a very fast and robust SQL database 
server
MariaDB-compat.x86_64 : MariaDB: a very fast and robust SQL database 
server
MariaDB-connect-engine.x86_64 : MariaDB: a very fast and robust SQL 
database server
MariaDB-cracklib-password-check.x86_64 : MariaDB: a very fast and 
robust SQL database server
MariaDB-devel.x86_64 : MariaDB: a very fast and robust SQL database 
server
MariaDB-gssapi-client.x86_64 : MariaDB: a very fast and robust SQL 
database server
MariaDB-gssapi-server.x86_64 : MariaDB: a very fast and robust SQL 
database server
MariaDB-oqgraph-engine.x86_64 : MariaDB: a very fast and robust SQL 
database server
MariaDB-server.x86_64 : MariaDB: a very fast and robust SQL database 
server
MariaDB-shared.x86_64 : MariaDB: a very fast and robust SQL database 
server
MariaDB-test.x86_64 : MariaDB: a very fast and robust SQL database 
server
mariadb-libs.x86_64 : The shared libraries required for MariaDB/MySQL 
clients
$ yum -y install MariaDB-server MariaDB-client galera percona-xtrabackup-24
$ mysql --version
mysql  Ver 15.1 Distrib 10.1.31-MariaDB, for Linux (x86_64) using readline 5.1
```